# Using "to" with "listen"

Tags: prepositions

What is the rule for using the verb **listen**?

Should I always add a preposition?

Is this sentence correct?

> I just listen carefully.

Comment: How can you add the preposition to in your sentence? A preposition can usually be added before a noun or pronoun. You can say: *I just listen to (something/somebody) carefully*.

Comment: That's exactly my question. I think it must be after `listen`  in my sentence example. But I'm not sure. @mahmudkoya

Comment: More context would be helpful here. For example, if you are writing fiction and it's already clear to the reader what you are listening to, based on preceding text, then the sentence is fine as it is. That isn't necessarily the case if you're writing something more formal.